# fish shell prompt: fish not reading fish_prompt.fish nor fish_right_prompt.fish

Tags: shell, ubuntu, fish

To make some minor changes to the fish prompt, I modified fish_prompt.fish/fish_right_prompt.fish files in the ~/.config/fish/ directory, but that does not change anything.

'functions --details fish_prompt' returns nothing, and 'functions --all fish_prompt' spits out:

```
# Defined via `source`
function fish_prompt
    set -l last_status $status
    if set -q CONDA_LEFT_PROMPT
        __conda_add_prompt
    end
    return_last_status $last_status
    __fish_prompt_orig
end
```

Where do I need to go from here to modify the prompt - I just need to add timestamp and a newline at the end of the prompt?

I have omf, git-plugin installed both of which might be superseding the fish_prompt and fish_right_prompt functions.  I am on a ubuntu system.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Though there are several fish_prompt.fish functions scattered around - eight of them in my case as revealed by the 'find' command, the one that seems to matter under omf is:

```
~/.local/share/omf/themes/<your_current_theme>/fish_prompt.fish
```

I ended up modifying that to get to what I wanted!